# How to create Target that always runs at the end of a build

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I've got a vxcproj with configuration type Driver and am trying to edit the project file to add a custom target that will always run at the end of building the project. I want it to run even if the standard build system detects it doesn't need to build anything.

I'm having a hard time trying to work out where to attach my target. If I attach to AfterBuild or PostBuildEvent, my target won't run if there's nothing to build.

If you're interested, I need this target to run run StampInf and Inf2Cat tasks as the built in versions of those don't suit my purposes. The built in ones always run and dirty outputs, causing knock on rebuilding which I don't want in an incremental build.

Comment: I've hacked something by adding a dummy file to the project with a custom build step on it that has Additional Dependencies for inputs my after build target needs, and Outputs for its outputs. The custom build step just echo's out some text. But, it causes the build to run, which then means that AfterBuild will run, and my custom Target will then run. There must be an easier way!

Answer (score 1):

Add a project of type General + Makefile.  VS cannot optimize the build for these type of projects, the custom Build Command Line setting you specify always runs.  You'll typically need to set the project dependencies to ensure it runs last.